# Wordpress: Let user select the number of posts shown per page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to build a function where the visitor can select the number of posts shown per page like this:

[image]

Where do I start and how do I achieve this? I am currently using query_post to list all the posts:

```
<?php 
$paged = 1;
query_posts(array( 'showposts'=> 10, 'post_type' => 'post', 'category_name' => 'jobseeker-announcements', 'order' => 'DESC', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'paged' => get_query_var('paged'))); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="post-list">
    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
    <p class="datetime"><span>Date Posted:</span> <?php the_time('m/j/Y'); ?></p>
    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
<!--/post-list--></div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: In default it show 10 post per page if you like to show post as visitor then you need to get custom WordPress query along with custom pagination and using get method you can set post per page and current pagination which will be use in query limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jquery `change` function.

```
 <?php 
if(isset($_GET['pageVal'])){
  $showposts = esc_sql($_GET['pageVal']);
}else{
  $showposts = 10;
}
    $paged = 1;
    query_posts(array( 'showposts'=> $showposts, 'post_type' => 'post', 'category_name' => 'jobseeker-announcements', 'order' => 'DESC', 'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page, 'paged' => get_query_var('paged'))); ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="post-list">
        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
        <p class="datetime"><span>Date Posted:</span> <?php the_time('m/j/Y'); ?></p>
        <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
    <!--/post-list--></div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

<select class='page-select'>
<option value='10'>10</option>
<option value='10'>20</option>
<option value='10'>30</option>
</select>
<script>
jQuery.ready(function(){
 $('.page-select').change(function(){
  $(location).attr('href', window.location.href+'?pageVal='+$('.page-select').val());
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: I made a little modification though, since it's not getting the value of pageVal properly for some reason

 if(isset($_GET['pageVal'])){
  $pages = $_GET['pageVal'];
  $showposts = $pages;
 } else {
  $showposts = 10;
 }

Comment: Use esc_sql function to avoid sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

May be it's perfect code for your solution.

```
    <?php 

    if(isset($_GET['page'])){
        $posts_per_page = esc_sql($_GET['page']);
    } else {
         $posts_per_page = 10;
    }

    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged')) ? get_query_var( 'paged') : 1;

    query_posts(
        array( 
             'post_type' => 'post',
             'category_name' => 'jobseeker-announcements',
             'order' => 'DESC', 
             'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
             'paged' => get_query_var('paged'))); 

    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <div class="post-list">
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <p class="datetime"><span>Date Posted:</span> <?php the_time('m/j/Y'); ?></p>
            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
        </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <select class="page-select">
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="20">30</option>
    </select>


    <script>

    jQuery.ready(function(){

        $('.page-select').change(function(){ 

        var checkIndex = window.location.href.indexOf('?');

        if( checkIndex > -1 ){
            var Link = window.location.href.substr(0, checkIndex-1);
            $(location).attr('href', Link+'?page='+$('.page-select').val());
        } else {
            $(location).attr('href', window.location.href+'?page='+$('.page-select').val());
        }

        });
    });

    </script>
```