# How would one set `posts_per_page` in WP with a BS4 dropdown, using the URL?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to provide my users with a method for changing the amount of items shown on page at any given time. But I'm not entirely sure how to go about it;

I've seen an older post on stack [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40077395/wordpress-let-user-select-the-number-of-posts-shown-per-page), but `$showposts` is depreciated, and now we also have the `pre_get_posts` filter. Which I thought might be able to do the job as required.

> **The Question:**
>
> Whats the best way to pass my anchors *data attribute* to WP's, `posts_per_page` param either using `pre_get_posts` filter or not?

---

### **EDIT:** 13 JULY 22:47

**Here's what I have:**

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn btn-sm dropdown-toggle px-0 mr-3" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Show:
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item active" href="javascript:;" data-handle="display" data-value="15">15 items per page</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:;" data-handle="display" data-value="30">30 items per page</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:;" data-handle="display" data-value="45">45 items per page</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:;" data-handle="display" data-value="60">60 items per page</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**My Filter `functions.php`**

```
// . Custom Search for Catalogue items
// . =================================
function catalogue_search( $query ) {

    if (isset($_GET['display'])) {
        $selValue = $_GET['display'];
    } else {
        $selValue = 15;
    }

    if ( $query->is_search() && 'products' === $query->get( 'post_type' ) ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', $selValue );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'catalogue_search' );
```

**My JQ.**

```
$("document").ready(function() {

  sortBy = null;
  display = null;

  setTimeout(function() {

    if ($(".dropdown-menu a").data('handle') == 'sort_by') {
      sortBy = '&' + $(this).data('handle') + '=' + $(this).data('value');
    }

    if ($(".dropdown-menu a").data('handle') == 'display') {
      display = '&' + $(this).data('handle') + '=' + $(this).data('value');
    }

    $('.btn-group').find('.active').trigger('click');

  }, 10);

  $(".dropdown-menu a").click(function() {

    if ($(this).data('handle') == 'sort_by') {
      sortBy = '&' + $(this).data('handle') + '=' + $(this).data('value');
    }

    if ($(this).data('handle') == 'display') {
      display = '&' + $(this).data('handle') + '=' + $(this).data('value');
    }

    $(this).closest('.btn-group').find(".dropdown-menu a").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');    

    $(this).closest('.btn-group').find('.appended').remove();
    $(this).closest('.btn-group').find('button').append('<span class="appended">' + $(this).text() + '</span>'); 

    window.location.hash = sortBy + display;    

  });

});
```

This [**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Beaniie/x71kyoc9/88/) should give you a working example of my current BS4 dropdowns.

**NOTE:**

With the new JS as per @Chris's suggestion, my url now reads as such;
`domain.com/?s=&post_type=products&submit=#&sort_by=recent&display=15`

I figured it was a `$GET` issue, but I'm not sure how to resolve it...

> `var_dump($_GET);` displays the following;

```
array(3) { 
    ["s"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["post_type"]=> string(8) "products" 
    ["submit"]=> string(0) "" 
}
```

It should display;

```
array(3) { 
    ["s"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["post_type"]=> string(8) "products" 
    ["submit"]=> string(0) ""
    ["display"]=> string(0) "" 
}
```

With that in mind, I added;

```
// . Add Query Vars
// . =======================
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ) {
  $vars[] = 'display';
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );
```

The issue still persists. :/

Comment: You are attempting to submit the form via AJAX. Have you setup your ajax actions? `add_action( 'wp_ajax_action', 'func' )`? That will be your first step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. From what I can see, you are attempting to submit the user selected option via AJAX. However, the `pre_get_posts` filter is used to filter the default WordPress query. Since you are submitting via AJAX, WP is not going to run any default queries, so `pre_get_posts` is mostly useless here.

You really have two options,

1. Ditch AJAX. In this case, instead of sending the selected option to the server async, you could append it to the url. So if the user is on domain.com/blog, upon selecting an option, you could redirect the user to the same url with the option appended as a query string.

```
$(".dropdown-menu a").click(function() {

    //get value
    //...

    //redirect
    window.location = 'domain.com/blog?posts_per_page=' + value;

});
```

WordPress may be able to pick up on that query string and handle the logic behind the query for you. If not, you can listen for this value (or a custom value) and then use `pre_get_posts` to filter.

```
//
function customize_query_params( $query ) {

    //only if our customization query var is set
    if( ! isset( $_GET['display'] ) )
        return $query;

    //never trust the user
    $display = filter_var( $_GET['display'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );

    //if $display != something we want, change it to be safe

    //customize the query
    $query->set('posts_per_page', $display);

    //
    return $query;
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'customize_query_params');
```

This should work fine with pagination as well, since the page parameters are also passed to WP in the url.

2. Your other option is to stick with AJAX. First, you need to make sure you are registering your AJAX handlers correctly in WP. I would have a look at the [docs here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)). Once you properly register your AJAX handler, you can run the query yourself, and return the results to the front end.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_custom_action', 'filter_by_user_option' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_custom_action', 'filter_by_user_option' );

function filter_by_user_option() {

    //get the value you submitted
    $limit = filter_var( $_POST['attribute'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );

    //get posts
    $posts = get_posts([
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => $limit,
        'paged' => 1
    ]);

    //return a response to the frontend. You could output JSON, or raw HTML
    header("Content-type: application/json");
    die( json_encode($posts) );

}

//front end
$(".dropdown-menu a").click(function() {

    //get value
    //...

    //redirect
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '<?php echo admin_url(‘admin-ajax.php’) ?>',
        data: {
            action: 'custom_action',
            attribute: value
        },
        success: function(res) {

            //res = array of posts. do something with this

        }
    });

});
```

I am a big fan of AJAX, but in this case, you have more work cut out for you going the AJAX route vs the url query string route. If you want pagination for example, you are going to have to track the current page, and pass that information along with your request.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer, I did originally plan to go the url route but I thought Ajax would be simpler. "Little did I know right?". I'll take another look at the URL option for the time being. :) Thanks again. +1

Comment: I've updated to my latest attempt, is this what you were thinking?

Comment: Close. You are setting a hash on the url. You need to set a query string (?display=15). Then, you can check for its existence in pre_get_posts and modify the query as needed. I updated the first part of my answer to show this.

Comment: Why do we return the query straight after `if( ! isset( $_GET['display'] ) )` ?

Comment: We only want our modification to run if the user made a selection. So that line checks to see if our url var is set, and if it is NOT set, it returns the query, unmodified, so WP can process as usual

Comment: I see, sadly I'm getting no response at all from the filter, what so ever. It's almost as if it cannot read the `$display` var... :(

Comment: Tough to debug without seeing the full source, but just add a lot of debug output. I would add a die("test"); after each line until I figured out where it was failing.

Comment: The hash symbol in your url is likely the issue. The hash is a reserved character for urls, so everything after it is being treated like a anchor and not a query string. Remove the hash and you should be good. `...submit=#&sort_by...`

Comment: How do you remove the hash if it's a link thats being used? It will always add a hash right?

Comment: `return false` from your on click handler. That will prevent the default functionality of the link. Also see https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: +! you we right the hash was the issue, though I can see a problem as the only way I could remove the has is by removing `window.location.hash` and replacing it with `window.location.search`. This however leaves my Jquery looping infinitely and my url now reads as follows when the user interacts. `domain.com//?s=&post_type=products&submit=null&display=30&sort_by=popularnullnull&display=45/`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196432/discussion-between-chris-and-beaniie).